# 'module' object has no attribute 'question'. Class name considered an attribute?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, attributes

I'm trying to make a quiz for my project and I'm getting this error: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'question'`. I don't understand why it thinks my class is an attribute.

- questionbf.py is where I made the binary file.
- quizbf.py is where I'm trying to make the quiz scoring right.

**questionbf.py**

```
import pickle
class question:
     def __init__(self,a,b,c):
          self.q=a
          self.an=b
          self.o=c

f1=open("Question.DAT","wb")
n=input("Enter no. of Questions ")
for i in range(n):
     a=raw_input("Enter Question ")
     b=raw_input("Enter Answer ")
     c=raw_input("Enter Options ")
     s=question(a,b,c)
     pickle.dump(s,f1)
f1.close()
```

**quizbf.py**

```
import pickle

print '''Welcome to the revision quiz.'''

print
score=0
w=0
c=0
f1=open("Question.DAT","rb")
try:
    while True:
        s=pickle.load(f1)
        print s.q
        print s.o
        guess=input("Enter Choice ")
        if guess==s.a:
            print "Correct!!"
            print
            score=score+1
            c=c+1
        elif guess=="exit" or guess=="Exit":
            break
        else:
            w=w+1
            print "Incorrect. Better luck next time!!"
            print
except EOFError:
    f1.close()
print s
print w
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RUBY\Desktop\questionbf.py", line 32, in <module>
    s=pickle.load(f1)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1378, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1069, in load_inst
    klass = self.find_class(module, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 1126, in find_class
    klass = getattr(mod, name)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'question'
```

Comment: I don't know python but to me this sounds like it can't unpickle the objects because the class `question` is not defined.

Comment: 1) classes should be capitalized in Python. 2) Have you tried to `from questionbf import question`? In other words, you need to import the `question` class in order to have the module know about it

Comment: @cricket_007 You might have to create a separate `question.py` file with just the class definition in it (which you then import in both scripts). If you don't, I suspect python will run the whole `questionbf` script again.

Comment: This is a great question. One new to python and serialization would never catch the issue. Worked like a charm. Any function/class you need and pickled from main should be refered in main section only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pickle an instance of a class the class name is saved in the pickle to allow the reading program to import the necessary module and gain access to the required class. Unfortunately the class whose elements you are pickling is in the `__main__` module, which is the name Python gives to the module that is being executed.

When your second program reads the pickle, it therefore looks for the `question` class in the `__main__` module, which this time is the second program. So `pickle` complains that the given module (`__main__`) does not contain the required class (a defined class is an attribute of its module just like a method of a class is an attribute of the class).

The simplest fix is to move the `question` class to a separate module, which your first program explicitly imports (using something like `from new_module import question`). Your second program will then know it needs to import `new_module` in order to access the `question` class, which it will do automatically (*i.e.* with no need to explicitly import it).

Another way (suggested by @Doogle in a comment below) is to import the `question` class into the namespace of your main program before attempting the unpickle.

Comment: Just awsome. Never got the issue scratching head for over 1.5hr. Great response. Just to add, issue can be resolved if the class is imported in the __main__ of the python module where unpickling is called. This really helped.

Comment: Good point - noticed a couple of tyops so I slipped your suggestion in as an edit - thanks!

Comment: I still cannot do this. Can you explain for me in detail. Thanks.

Comment: Well the easiest way to fix quizbf.py is to add `from questionbf import question` at the top of the file. That way pickle will find the class where it expects to. Your traceback is misleading: it complains about a line from _quizbf.py_ but claims to be a traceback from _questionbf.py_.